# Create an arrayList from two other arrayList and keep only value that are identical in both arrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I have two `arrayList` that can **contain 0 or many** `int` and I need to create a new `arrayList` from these two with values that are in both. In this case `[4,23]`

**Example**

```
arrayList1 [3 ,4 ,7,23,12]
arrayList2 [13,4,17,23,15]
```

In this example I need a new `arrayList` containing `[4,23]`

Is there an easy way to do it with `.contains()` or some similar method. Or should I
loop through both list and check for equality and create the new list ?

Knowing that one or the other `arrayList` can be empty.

Thank you

Comment: Check the `java.util.Set` interface, I think it is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be more efficient with sets, but even just with lists, it's simple to use [`retainAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#retainAll-java.util.Collection-):

```
// Start by copying arrayList1
List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>(arrayList1);
result.retainAll(arrayList2);
```

That's assuming you *don't* want to modify `arrayList1`. If you don't mind about that, you can skip the first step:

```
arrayList1.retainAll(arrayList2);
```

You should strongly consider using sets if that's what you're *logically* talking about though.

Comment: Perfect, that is exactly what I'm looking for. I thought I would get downvote for this question... Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use [`retainAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#retainAll%28java.util.Collection%29):

```
list1.retainAll(list2);
```

Or if you don't want to modify `list1`:

```
List<Integer> intersection = new ArrayList<>(list1);
intersection.retainAll(list2);
```

Comment: I give the accepted answer to @Jon as he gave me some advices considering using sets to be more efficient but If I could accepted both I would have accepted yours too. Thank you +1

Comment: @Lorenzo No problem at all. Glad I could help in any case! :-)